# Getting a particular version of a branch

Tags: github, theano

Is there a way to download a particular version of a branch?

In particular I'd like to do a git clone of https://github.com/Theano/Theano now, and save a set of instructions on how to get the exact same version from github, regardless of future commits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

There is an easier way to do this on github if no further changes are expected. In github, you can navigate to the 'tree view' of a repository from your browser via the URL

```
https://github.com/<repo_name>/tree/<commit_sha>
```

Clicking on the 'Download ZIP' button on the right-hand navigation bar will download the codes of the repository up to that particular commit.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I think one way to make your user's (or whoever will be reading your instructions) life easier is to clone the entire repository as-is. Then if the current `HEAD` commit is the version you want and you don't plan on making/merging changes to your repository, you can just refer your user to this new repository; probably tagging it will be a good idea.

Otherwise, you can create a branch (and a tag) in your new repository with the specific commit by doing:

```
$ git checkout -b new_branch commit_sha // where commit_sha points to the version you wanted
```

Then you can refer your user to this new branch (or tag) in your repository, after they have cloned your repository.

I don't think there is a simple way to clone the [original repository](https://github.com/Theano/Theano) from an old commit without using `git reset`.

Comment: Hm...I don't see the "download zip" option -- https://github.com/Theano/Theano/commit/0e8f48e58e42d7c56dc027df921b7877d4d68d78

Comment: Change your URL from *commit/* to *tree/*. It's a button located on the lower left column, after 'Clone in Desktop'.

Comment: Ahhh, I see it now, for some reason the URL on my case was https://github.com/Theano/Theano/tree/<commit sha>, not https://github.com/Theano/tree/<commit sha> (https://github.com/Theano/Theano/tree/0e8f48e58e42d7c56dc027df921b7877d4d68d78)