# Git: Shallow copies from a specific commit

Tags: git, version-control

`git clone --depth N ...` creates a shallow clone with history limited to the last N revisions and I can use `git clone -b tag ...` to fetch the commits reachable from `tag`. However, is there a way to fetch a repository (or a branch thereof) from a specific (tagged) commit up to the branch head?

Say, for example, I'd like to clone only the history starting from a specific release tag. So if the last few commits in the remote look like this

```
[master]   ...
[master~1] ...
[master~2] ... <-- tag: x.x
[master~3] ...
...
```

Now I'd like to clone the history range `x.x~1..`, without having to manually count the number of revisions to give to `--depth`.

I guess the explanation given in the accepted answer to [Why Isn't There A Git Clone Specific Commit Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135216/why-isnt-there-a-git-clone-specific-commit-option) applies here as well, so there might not be a direct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there is no direct way, and this kind of counting or multiple-ref-based cloning would have to be implemented on the server side (the server delivering the initial shallow clone) for it to work within git's constraints.

There's an indirect way though: start with a depth 1 shallow clone, then deepen repeatedly until the tag appears.  Annoyingly, `git fetch --depth=<N>` won't pick up new tags (but you can use `git ls-remote` or similar to get everything once on the shallow-clone client, and watch for the SHA-1).  But I suspect this method would be so slow as to make it pretty worthless.

Answer (score 1):

If running at least Git 2.11 on both client and server side, there's a work-around if you know the date of the tagged commit and which branch it is on:

```
git clone --branch <branch that contains tag> --shallow-since=<date of tagged commit> <url>
```