# git shallow clone since specific commit

Tags: git, shallow-clone

I'd like to clone a repository with a longish history. I'm only interested in a few short-lived not-yet-merged feature branches and `master`.

In order to not confuse myself with all that past history and merged branches, I'd like to do a shallow clone starting at a specific commit SHA.

However, so far I've only found documentation on how to do shallow clones that only include the last `n` commits (`--depth`) resp, the commits since a specific date (`--shallow-since`).

Is there a way to specify a shallow-clone starting at a given commit?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612627

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not, which is kind of a shame since it would be easy for Git to implement.

Usually using `--depth` is sufficient: just start with a depth you think is enough, and if it's not, repeatedly fetch with `--deepen` or `--depth` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Still not possible yet, but if we know the datetime of the commit we want to create shallow clone of, we can use `git --shallow-since=<date>`, example if we know commit X was pushed at "2021-12-19T20:37:05Z", we can:

```
git clone --shallow-since="2021-12-19T20:37:05Z" <url>
```

will only give history from commit X

Answer (score -3):

What about creating a branch at that special commit and then `git clone --single-branch`?

Comment: i think that's the wrong way around: i want my history to *start* at the given commit, not to end.

Comment: yes. i also want all the branches (i'm interested in) that forked off after `xxx`.

Comment: Oh, OK, I re-read you question and you state explicitly you want "ot-yet-merged feature branches and master". Point taken.