# How to clone a repository of a specific commit ID?

Tags: git, gitlab, commit, git-clone

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to clone using HTTPs a repository (sample.com/component.git) but from a specific commit ID.

I really don't know where to start.
Should I fetch the repoistory, then checkout that commit ID and finally clone it?

```
git fetch sample.com/component.git
git checkout 9a36b9e79tbb9132c7020a5bd5694c7cefce8cff
git clone sample.com/component.git
```

OR

```
git clone sample.com/component.git 9a36b9e79tbb9132c7020a5bd5694c7cefce8cff
```

Any help in doing this correctly, or if there's a better way would be highly appreciated

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135216/why-isnt-there-a-git-clone-specific-commit-option

Comment: Git does not have a concept of a clone of a particular commit.  Cloning is a function on (whole) repositories.  Having cloned a repository, you can check out any commit you like into your clone's working directory.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - is that true?  I think the existence of the -single-branch branch option to the commit command says otherwise.  I don't know, however, if this what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @tadm123 - can you provide a bit more information about what you're trying to accomplish?  Do you want a repository that contains all of the history for a particular commit, or do you just want the files represented by a particular commit?

Comment: @CryptoFool I'll be honest this is a new job in software engineering which I have little experience, I have cloned a repository that has a components folder in it. He wants me to add into this component folder another submodule. I feel completely lost. This is the exact task: 
"add this special component as a submodule to compoennt folder as well

sample.com/component.git

9a36b9e79tbb9132c7020a5bd5694c7cefce8cff"

Comment: Apparently that url has a folder that he wants me added, but I'm not sure how exactly the commit ID comes into play here. I think he wants me to download that commit ID version of the repository...

Comment: @CryptoFool, I guess you mean `git clone --single-branch` (not `git commit -single-branch`).   But that's still a repository operation, and it yields a repository containing the full history of the tip of the specified branch.  It is not a clone of a single commit.

Comment: oops...yeah, that's what I meant. And as far as "a clone of a single commit" goes, that's exactly what I'm asking the OP to clarify...what do they mean by "clone a single commit".  I think you can actually clone a repo to contain just a single commit with `git clone --single-branch --branch <hash> --depth 1`.

Comment: In any case, if the objective is to set up a submodule, then I'm pretty sure that cloning is a red herring.

Comment: @JohnBollinger "cloning is a red herring".  agreed.

Comment: @John Bollinger Can you let me know if the task not about cloning, what exactly are they asking me to do? I'm a little confused, what does "setting up a submodule" mean?

Comment: @CryptoFool can you guys please let me know what is he reffering to when he says "setting up a submodule" if it's not about cloning?

Comment: @tadm123, a "submodule" is a specific structure within a Git repository.  Look up [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git clone particular version of remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555107/git-clone-particular-version-of-remote-repository)

Answer (score 11):

Try this 3 steps,

Step 1: clone the main repo:

```
git clone sample.com/component.git
```

Get inside the cloned repo `cd folder_name`. Now you have a working directory with latest version pulled and you want to move back to a specific commit id, here's how you can do it:

Step 2:

```bash
git reset --hard 9a36b9e79tbb9132c7 #(takes you back to that commit)
```

Step 3:

```
git clean -df #(cleans any untracked files/folders)
```

Comment: `git reset --hard 9a36b9e79tbb9132c7 #(takes you back to that commit)`. This does not really "take you back to that commit": it resets the current branch to point to that commit. A safer way would be `git checkout 9a36b9e79tbb9132c7`.